# facebook login api doesn't respond in phonegap wp8 app

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using phonegap 3.5.0-0.20.4 & wp8 platform. My FB.login call simply doesn't seem to do anything (no response). I checked other replies around similar problem, but none seem to help wp8 platform. Here is my sample code

```
FB.init({appId: "23...32", version: 'v2.0'});
FB.login(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response);
}, { scope: "email" });
```

My login call simply doesn't go through. I do have webbrowser & device plugins installed on the phonegap app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are deprecated documentation, try this
FB.login(['public_profile'], successCallbackFn, errorCallbackFn);

But this has no sense because facebook does not return callback functions on login after april's sdk update to version 3.14

Please let me know if facebook login will work for you.